# Whats the most amount of primes we can prove the existence of, that are less than some prime number squared?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Given some arbitrary prime number $p_n$

How many prime numbers can we prove exist which are smaller than ${p_n}^2?$

...Obviously we can say that $n$ primes must exist, but I think I can prove that $n + p_n - 1$ prime numbers must exists which are smaller than ${p_n}^2$.

Are there any better results?

Comment: The [prime number theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem#Non-asymptotic_bounds_on_the_prime-counting_function) gives much better bounds.

Comment: Isn't it an approximation?

Comment: The link I included gives concrete inequalities.

Comment: Wikipedia's banned in Turkey unfortunately... which concrete inequality is better?

Comment: For example, $2p_n>n+p_n-1$ is better, for $n\ge 7$.

Comment: just by Bertrand's postulate and algebra you can guess $k^2+k$ primes very roughly. where $p_n=2\cdot k+1$ or log of it base 2 rather.

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimeNumberTheorem.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [prime number theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem#Non-asymptotic_bounds_on_the_prime-counting_function) gives much better bounds. Here is a screenshot of some of those bounds, for those who can't use the link. The famous [paper of Rosser and Schoenfeld](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ijm/1255631807) is a good source for such inequalities.

[image: screenshot from Wikipedia]

Comment: Is there anyone who can see this site but can't see Wikipedia?

Comment: Turkey apparently